# Initialize variable number of ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to make a Dynamic Program using Eclipse. For this program, I need to define several (in fact too many ~ 200) sets. I have researched and found that I could use ArrayLists in order to store integers.

In the problem I am trying to solve, there are T (T being any integer) many different ArrayLists I need to create. I need to define a unique ArrayList for every value of T. For instance, for T=3 I will need to define three different ArrayLists where I will be able to store integers for every different index:

```
ArrayList T1 = new ArrayList();

ArrayList T2 = new ArrayList();

ArrayList T3 = new ArrayList();
```

The problem here is that I am clueless on how I may define as many ArrayLists as  T. I have tried to create a "for loop" in order to initialize these variables but as I expected it didn't turn out well (simply because I need different names for each ArrayList and I could not vary the name of every ArrayList) I was sure it wouldn't work (or at least I was sure that I was doing it wrong even if there is a way to do it - which I could not find by searching on the internet) but just to give an idea of what I was trying to do, the code looked like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<T; i++) {
    ArrayList T+i = new ArrayList(); //I tried to vary the name of the arraylist by adding the variable "i" next to T.
}
```

In the code above, I could not achieve to define indexes for the ArrayLists but please note that it would be extremely convenient if we can do this by adding indexes to ArrayLists.

As this is my very first attempt on Dynamic Programming I am a little lost and I appreciate all of your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, if I understand you question correctly you need to create arbitrary number ArrayLists and then you will select amongst those ArrayLists using an index?

Comment: Yes exactly, I will try to make it clearer in the question that I need the index. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions to your problem is to create an ArrayList of ArrayLists. E.g.,

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

However if you are using older JDKs you might need to use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<>>();
```

Then you can initialize them if necessary:

```
for (int i=0; i<T; i++) {
    listOfLists.add(new ArrayList()); 
}
```

and use them like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> firstList = listOfLists.get(0);
```

For multi-dimensional arraylist

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i<T; i++) {
    map.put(i, new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()); 
}
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tempList = map.get(0);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: You can also pass the size of the arraylist as an argument as @Ruthi Ruth has suggested

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's much clearer in my mind now. Would it also be possible to add a second index to the ArrayLists? Would I need to define three ArrayLists within each other to achieve the second index?

Comment: Do you mean like a list of two dimensional arrays?

Comment: Yes exactly. In this case I'm assuming I need several ArrayLists with two indexes instead of just one.

Comment: @StoryMaths that's one way to do it. Updated solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a list of lists, like:

```
int T = 10;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> array = new ArrayList<>(T);
for(int i = 0; i < T;i++){
        array.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

with `array.get(i)` you can get your specific list to fill for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think it would be possible to implement this solution into cases with two indexes? Say, if we need to create our ArrayLists using two indexes (i and j) instead of just i?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over the names, you could simply make a unique map containing name as key and arraylist as value:

```
HashMap arrayMap = new HashMap();
for(int i = 0; i< 200; i++){
    arrayMap.put("T"+i, new ArrayList());
}
```

**Edit**
Answering your question:

```
int MAX_Y = 100;
int MAX_X = 100;
HashMap<K, V> arrayMap = new HashMap();
for(int i = 0; i< MAX_X; i++){
    for(int x = 0; x < MAX_Y; x++){
        arrayMap.put("T_"+i+"_"+x, new ArrayList());
    }
}

//To retrive array
arrayMap.get("T_15_20");
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative answer, this solution could be a little more convenient in my case. I have never tried using maps in Java before. Do you think it would be possible to add a second index to the code above? I'm guessing another for loop outside of the one in your code might do the job?
How could I call the array lists later on in this case?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This probably will work perfectly fine for me. I tried to implement the code in my problem but the variables K and V seem to be causing an error, even though I initialize them (as integers). Do I need to initialize them in another type? Sorry for bombarding you with questions, it's the first time I will be using HashMap - that's why I am so hesitant.

Comment: In this particular case the K is a string and not an integer.

Comment: I have defined K as a String and V as an integer but I still get an error: "K cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
 int T=10;
    ArrayList[] arrayLists = new ArrayList[T];
    for(int i=0;i<arrayLists.length;i++){
      arrayLists[i] = new ArrayList();
  }
```

You can later access any ArrayList as arrayLists[i] where i will be the list number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a 2D list for every key, you can use [ListMultimap from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html):

```
final ListMultimap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
map.put(7, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
map.put(7, Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
map.put(1, Arrays.asList(9));

System.out.println(map); // prints '{1=[[9]], 7=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}'
```

Alternatively, if you want only one list per key, you can do the following:

```
final List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
list.add(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));

System.out.println(list); // prints '[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]'
```